# How to use placeholder attribute in <form:select>?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My jsp code like this,

```
<form:select path="metaFieldId" cssStyle="width: 190px;" placeholder="Select Filter"    onchange="selectMetaField(${metaFieldId})">
    <form:option value="" label="" />
    <form:options items="${metaFields}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

Can anybody help my?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML `select` tag does not support `placeholder` attribute.
If you use `select` you can use the first option to display the placeholder text:

```
<form:select path="metaFieldId" cssStyle="width: 190px;" onchange="selectMetaField(${metaFieldId})">
    <form:option value="" label="Select Filter" />
    <form:options items="${metaFields}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: how to deactive the first option - so the placeholder is not part of the real selection options